# Changing background Javascript project

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a background that changes the color on the time of day. However I can't seem to fix my parameters. Put them in variables. Input from HTML to JavaScript is fixed.

Feels like I'm missing something very obvious. (new to JavaScript and coding in general).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      function alerts(alert1, alert2, alert3, alert4, alert5, alert6) {
        var hours = new Data().getHours();

        if (alert1.empty() || alert2.empty() || alert3.empty() || alert4.empty() || alert5.empty() || alert6.empty()) {

          alert1 = 0;
          alert2 = 12;
          alert3 = 12;
          alert4 = 17;
          alert5 = 17;
          alert6 = 24;

          if (hours >= alert1 && hours < alert2) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fceea1";
          } else if (hours >= alert3 && hours < alert4) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#dbbc0a";
          } else if (hours >= alert5 && hours < alert6) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#706527";
          } else {

          }
        }
      };
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: white;
  font-size: 150px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welkom</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js">
    alerts(0, 12, 12, 17, 17, 20);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think .empty() dumps content from an DOM element, not a test as to whether or not a value exists ... try it without the conditional block testing the alert# variables?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. For example, it should probably be `new Date().getHours();` instead of `new Data().getHours();`

Comment: Plus your calling `new Data()` it should be `new Date()` (with an E)

Answer (score 2):

The working code, explanations are after the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welkom</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script> <!-- Includes Jquery -->

<script src="js/index.js"></script> <!-- Includes the script for background change -->

</body>

</html>
```

**js/index.js**

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    function alerts (alert1, alert2, alert3, alert4) {
        var hours = new Date().getHours(); //The proper inclusion of date

      if (alert1 == undefined) { //Undefined is JS keyword which set 
        alert1=0; //when variable was declared, but undefined, no defenition
      }

      if (alert2 == undefined) {
        alert2=12;
      }

      if (alert3 == undefined) {
        alert3=17;
      }

      if (alert4 == undefined) {
        alert4=24;
      }

    //The redundant variables were removed and you can reuse variable
    // for multiple if statements
    if (hours >= alert1 && hours < alert2) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fceea1";
    } else if (hours >= alert2 && hours < alert3) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#dbbc0a";
    } else if (hours >= alert3 && hours < alert4) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#706527";
    } else { //Just a quick comment, you are able not to even print
      // else statement, you can just leave it out
    }

    }
    alerts(); // Calls the function
    }); // the ) bracket closes Jquery
```

**css/style.css**

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: white;
  font-size: 150px;
  color: #333;
} /*Unchanged*/
```

**Explanations**

There was 5 main problems with your code.

First:

**The 'if' statement**

Your 'if' statement for checking if the values were empty **ALSO** included the code for execution the function itself.
So if you called your code with variables set, the code won't execute.

Second:

**The wrong import of jQuery**

What you actually meant was `var hours = new Date().getHours();` instead of `var hours = new Data().getHours();`.
Its very simple error, easy fix.

Third:

**alert1.empty()**
This is not correct approach. Much cleaner is to to check like `alert1 == undefined`.The `undefined` keyword is for variable which were declared, but they haven't been defined. Plus not all JavaScript interpreters (browsers) support .empty().

Fourth:

**The or in the 'if' statement**

The operator `||` is evil. In code example you provided if any of those variables missed it will override **ALL** variables to default values you specified. Because of that I have divided them in separate 'if' statements.

Fifth:

**Redundant variables**

The variables `alert2` and `alert3` are redundant, like variables `alert4` and `alert5`. By redundant I mean they have the same value, while you can just use one variable, but in multiple 'if' statements. Remember: You can use the same variable in multiple 'if' statements. I removed two variables and modified version of the code execution is:

```
if (hours >= alert1 && hours < alert2) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fceea1";
} else if (hours >= alert2 && hours < alert3) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#dbbc0a";
} else if (hours >= alert3 && hours < alert4) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#706527";
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think experimenting with random little projects is a great way to learn, so I made a simple script that does what you described with comments so you can try to understand how everything works!

The color looks pretty odd and ugly, but that's just because of the values I gave it, so feel free to mess around with weights and different measurements of time!

```js
function changeColor() {
  var d = new Date(); // Creates a 'date' object
  var ms = d.getMilliseconds(); // Gets the current millisecond
  var minute = d.getMinutes(); // Gets the current minute
  var second = d.getSeconds(); // Gets the current second
  /*
  Other methods of obtaining the time:
  d.getFullYear()       Get the year as a four digit number (yyyy)
  d.getMonth()         Get the month as a number (0-11)
  d.getDate()           Get the day as a number (1-31)
  d.getHours()          Get the hour (0-23)
  d.getTime()           Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
  d.getDay()           Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
  */
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + ms/4 + ',' + minute + ',' + second + ')';
  // This sets the backgroundColor of the document to an RGB value where red is the milliseconds, green is the minute, and blue is the second
  // Note: I divided the millisecond value by 4 because the highest possible value is 255 and the millisecond value can reach 999.
  // It would still work without dividing it, but the color wouldn't change as much because it would interpret 255-999 as 255
}

var interval = setInterval(changeColor, 100) // Runs the changeColor() function every .1 seconds
// Note: This would still work if I didn't set it as a variable, but it's good practice to set intervals as variables so you can use clearInterval(variable)
```